# Overlapping of paint GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, for-loop, repaint

So basically I'm trying to create countdown when my code is run,
which is fine and working the only problem I have is that instead of the 
numbers disappearing and being replaced by the new value of i, they stay the new value overlaps the existing number. I tried to use repaint () to fix this but it's not working. I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing or if I should try a different way altogether.

here's the code for the timer:

```
public void timer (Graphics g,int x){
    x=550;

    for (int i = time;i>0;i--){
        g.setColor(deepPlum);
        g.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        g.drawString("time: "+i, x, 650);
        repaint();

    } 
}
```

Comment: Your out-of-context code snippet raises a lot more questions then we can answer. Consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - focusing "how" the code is executed (how is the method called? How is the painting actually down? Where does `Graphics` come from?), because at the moment, the code kind of scares me

Comment: Guesses - You're painting outside the context of the required paint cycle; You're using alpha based colors for the background to try and implement transparency; you're not honouring the prescribed paint chain requirements (by not calling the `super` paint method) - something else I can't think off the top of my head

Comment: I do call the super paint method but in the paint method. I know that is fine because all of my other graphics are working fine.

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong which is not demonstrated in your out-of-context example. If you're calling `timer` instead of the `paint` method, then you're using the wrong approach, which probably explains the overall issue

Comment: As for the background I haven't touched that at all. I'm using the basic gray one that comes with JFrame

Comment: A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would clear up the misunderstands and remove the guess work - at the moment, I'm left with guessing that `timer` is been called from within the context of one of the component's `paint` methods, if so, it would at least explain what you are seeing, but I'd like to remove that doubt if I can

Answer (score 1):

## At a "guess"

I don't like guessing, but it seems we're not going to get a runnable example which would provide a clear understand of how the problem is been generated.

### Evidence...

> I do call the super paint method but in the paint method. I know that is fine because all of my other graphics are working fine.

This "suggests" that `timer` is been called as part of the normal Swing "paint" cycle.  If that's true, it explains the reason for the issue.

This...

```
public void timer (Graphics g,int x){
    x=550;

    for (int i = time;i>0;i--){
        g.setColor(deepPlum);
        g.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        g.drawString("time: "+i, x, 650);
        repaint();

    } 
}
```

is simply painting all the numbers over each other, each time a paint cycle occurs, which really isn't how a count down timer should be painted.

Instead, it should simply be painting the remaining time, a single value, and not try and paint all of them.

You can think of a "paint cycle" as a "frame", it paints a snap-shot of the current state of the component.  You need to paint a number of these "frames" in order to animate the changes from one point in time to another.

I would, again, strongly, recommend that you take the time to read through [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to better understand how painting actually works.

Without more evidence, I would suggest, a Swing `Timer` would be a better solution.  This could be used to calculate the remaining time and schedule a `repaint` on a regular bases.

Because I seem to do this kind of thing a lot, I wrapped up the core functionality into a simple `Counter` class, which has a "duration" (or runtime) and can calculate the `duration` it's been running, the `remaining` time and the `progress` as a percentage of the `duration` and `runTime`, probably more then you need, but it gives you the basics from which to start.

Because painting is a imprecise art (the time between paint cycles is variable, even when using a `Timer`), I've used a "time" based approach, rather then a simple "counter".  This gives you a much higher level of precision when dealing with these type of scenarios

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                // The following two lines just set up the
                // "default" size of the frame
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JComponent {

        private Counter counter;

        public TestPane() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (counter == null) {
                        counter = new Counter(Duration.of(10, ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
                        counter.start();
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (counter != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();

                long time = counter.getRemaining().getSeconds();

                int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(Long.toString(time))) / 2;
                int y = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
                g2d.drawString(Long.toString(time), x, y);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

    public static class Counter {

        private Duration length;
        private LocalDateTime startedAt;

        public Counter(Duration length) {
            this.length = length;
        }

        public Duration getLength() {
            return length;
        }

        public void start() {
            startedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
        }

        public void stop() {
            startedAt = null;
        }

        public Duration getDuration() {
            if (startedAt == null) {
                return null;
            }
            Duration duration = Duration.between(startedAt, LocalDateTime.now());
            if (duration.compareTo(getLength()) > 0) {
                duration = getLength();
            }
            return duration;
        }

        public Double getProgress() {
            if (startedAt == null) {
                return null;
            }
            Duration duration = getDuration();
            return Math.min(1.0, (double) duration.toMillis() / length.toMillis());
        }

        public Duration getRemaining() {
            if (startedAt == null) {
                return null;
            }
            Duration length = getLength();
            Duration time = getDuration();

            LocalDateTime endTime = startedAt.plus(length);
            LocalDateTime runTime = startedAt.plus(time);

            Duration duration = Duration.between(runTime, endTime);
            if (duration.isNegative()) {
                duration = Duration.ZERO;
            }

            return duration;
        }
    }

}
```

Before someone tells me how `clearRect` would solve the issue, it's important to note that `clearRect` will do two things.  One, it would only display the "last" value of the loop, which is clearly not what the OP wants, and it will fill the specified area with the current background color of the `Graphics` context, which "may" not be what the OP want's (as it will paint a nice rectangle over the top of what ever else was painted before it).

If used properly, the Swing painting system will prepare the `Graphics` context BEFORE the component's `paint` method is called, rendering the need for using `clearRect` mute

Answer (score -4):

Call clearRect to restore the background for a rectangular region before drawing again

Comment: All things been equal, the `Graphics` context should be getting "prepared" by the Swing paint engine, including either filling it with the background color of the component or clear the context if it's transparent, which suggest that the OP is painting out of the required paint cycle or they are doing something else elicit (like breaking the paint chain), which in any case `clearRect` either won't solve the issue or it will simply mask a bigger problem

Comment: That's my point, nothing is evident in her code, making the question unanswerable

Comment: Well she did say she has strings being drawn on top of other strings, so clearRect will fix that.  Because she said that, we know that what you said is incorrect.

Comment: `clearRect` will "mask" the bigger problem - so instead of actually helping the OP in the long term, you're actually harming them, which means we'll get more questions about why the code breaks further down the track, which means we will need to highlight the "bad advice" they were given in the past, which just makes us all look ... well, bad :P - what is actually need (from the OP) is a MCV - then we can all stop guessing

Comment: So I'm harming someone by answering their question.  Frankly, you need to get over yourself.  The only one who looks bad here is you for being so dictatorial.

Comment: And by the way, there is no "bigger" problem.

Comment: Well, forgive me for trying to help you both. *"And by the way, there is no "bigger" problem"* - Unless you have access to the code they are using, you can be sure of that, no one can, but if you're happy with your answer, I'll leave you with it - again, I'm sorry for trying to help improve the quality of your answer

Comment: Telling someone their question is unanswerable, then telling the person who answered the question to stop, that is not helpful to anyone.

Comment: Leading some astray with a potential "hack" isn't helpful to anyone either - finding out "what" is creating the issue would be more help in providing a suitable solution to the answer - as ill fated as it might sound, I'm just trying to lift both the quality of the question and the answers provided - and asking you to consider the fact their might be a "bigger issue" at play isn't meant to be "harmful" to anyone, again, I'm sorry you've taken my suggestions the wrong way

Comment: Get over yourself.  This is not the Korean peace negotiations, nor is this a discussion on the nuances of graphics programming, this is a very simple question about strings appearing on top of other strings.  RIddle me this: why does clearRect exist in the first place if not to clear something already there?

Comment: *"RIddle me this: why does clearRect exist in the first place except to clear something already there?"* - Why isn't the pre-extsing paint chain already taking care of it? If it were working correctly there would no need to call `clearRect` - The fact is, you could be right, you could also be wrong

Comment: That's not an answer.  The people who wrote the library and the people who reviewed it saw a reason to have clearRect in it.

Comment: Just because it exists, doesn't mean it's the "right" tool for the job - I'm just saying we're lacking context to know what the "right" approach would be - if you're confident with your answer, then by all means, ride with it

Comment: I disagree with @MadProgrammer only in so much as they never explicitly said *"This is a **crap** answer"*. It's worse than noise, in that it is depending on a hack (which may or may not work, even for this situation) instead of discovering the true nature of the problem. It definitely earns a 'minus one'.

Comment: On the one hand you people claim there is not enough said to answer, then all of a sudden you can claim definitively that calling a method in the java library is a hack.  The clearRect method is a hack, according to you guys.  You guys are nuts. The method exists for a reason.

Comment: `So I'm harming someone by answering their question.` yes because you don't know the context of the question and therefore can't suggest the best solution. The fact that the OP is trying to paint a String in a loop means they also don't understand how painting works. The OP will only ever see the last value since all the repaint() requests in the loop will be consolidated into a single paint() request. Without proper context of how the code is used a proper answer can't be given. Sometimes that is the best answer.